# Silverlight - how to catch mouse out

Tags: .net, silverlight

My XAML page has popup element (with usercontrol inside), which should be hidden when mouse will out this popup. How to do it? I try to catch MouseLeave, but it does not work...

```
    <Popup Name="popup" MouseLeave="popup_MouseLeave">
        <blib:TimeZones></blib:TimeZones>
    </Popup>

    private void popup_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your child controls are absorbing the MouseLeave event, instead of your `Popup` control. If your child control is the same size as the popup, try handling its `MouseLeave` event instead.

As a side note, would a `Tooltip` be more appropriate?

Comment: Tooltip is hidden when you move mouse on tooltip.